# How to find nested directories?

Tags: linux, file, bash, path

I have directory tree like:

```
dir11/dir21/dir31......./dirn1
dir12/dir22/dir32......./dirn2
dir13/dir23/dir33......./dirn3
```

Depths are different. Does it possible find all paths on which exists directory with file x.txt that has length>0 ? May be need use bash script?
Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I believe GNU [find](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) can match all your criteria by itself:

```
$ find /top/dir -not -empty -type f -name x.txt -printf '%h\n'
```

The above recursively searches `/top/dir` for non-empty (`-not -empty`), regular (`-type f`) files named `x.txt`, and prints the directories leading to these files (`-printf '%h\n'`).

Comment: @Benoit, you're absolutely right. Answer fixed, thanks for the heads-up :)

Comment: Hmmwait, for me the OP wants to find the _directories_ in which there is such a file, this finds files, not directories

Comment: @fge, this finds files, but prints directories (the magic is in `-printf '%h\n'`), which I think is what the questioner wants.

Answer (score 3):

```
find . -type f -name *x.txt -size +1
```

Answer (score 3):

Probably with find you can use:

```
find /top/dir -type f -name x.txt -size +1b -printf '%h\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You pretty much need that, yes...

```
for dir in $(find /the/root/dir -type d); do
    if [ ! -f "$dir/x.txt" ]; then
        continue
    fi
    size=$(stat -c %s "$dir/x.txt")
    if [ "$size" != "0" ]; then
       echo $dir
    fi
done
```